How was damno derived from damnum?
Oxford Latin Dictionary says that damno (tr. condemn) was derived from damnum (n. loss; waning). How is sense "loss, waning" related to and derived from sense "condemn"?

Damnum means "loss" but more broadly means "injury", and in legal terms, refers to a legal punishment or penalty. So the verb damnō can mean to pass judgement or sentence someone to a particular punishment. From there it's a small step to "condemn".
